# Openning NetworkManager's edit connections window from terminal

Tags: gnome, ssh, network-manager

I need to open NetworkManager's edit connections window from terminal (for `ssh -X` ).
What is the command that opens it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The correct command is `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: I found `sudo nmtui` much more useful, as suggested by @asac below

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, use `(sudo) nmtui` to get as close to a GUI as you can get in a terminal.

No need to forward X to add, edit or delete connections via this user-friendly interface.

Comment: This is much more useful than `nm-connection-editor`

Comment: `nmtui` is great but some things cannot be controlled with it